# i am using fullCalender and dayrender is not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i am using fullCalender i want to change the color of some specific days i have also created overlay which is shown whenever user clicks on any specific day...which is working quite fine 
now i want to change the color of cells using dayrender but its not working kindly help me....

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cal').fullCalendar({
     dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        var date=date.format('DD/MM/YY');
        var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
        var label_div=jQuery('<div id=label_date><img  src="../icons/cal.png"></div');
        var label=jQuery('<label id=current_date>'+date+'</label>');
        label.appendTo(label_div);
        label_div.appendTo(overlay);
        var cross=jQuery('<a href="#" id="close" onclick="frameWarp();"><img src="../icons/cross.png"></a>');
        cross.appendTo(overlay);
        var overlay_body=jQuery('<div id=overlay_body></div>');
        overlay_body.appendTo(overlay);
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);


     }//overly complete
      // now change color code which isnt working

        dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
}

     })

  });
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

date is a moment object, so you need to compare against another moment object.

Try this:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    if (moment().isSame(date, 'day')) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```